# A polynomial and its reciprocal expansion

Tags: real-analysis, cv.complex-variables, polynomials, taylor-series

Suppose $f(x)=\prod_{k=1}^n(x-a_k)$ where all $a_k>0$.

Expand the function $\frac1f$ at $\infty$ so that
$$\frac1{f(x)}=\frac{b_n}{x^n}+\frac{b_{n+1}}{x^{n+1}}+\cdots.$$
**Does it follow that each $b_m$ is positive, for $m\geq n$?**

Comment: Why the down vote? Is the problem too easy or ...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's pretty easy.
$$
\frac{1}{f(x)}
= \prod_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{x-a_k}
= x^n \prod_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{1-a_k/x}
= x^n \prod_{k=1}^n \sum_{i=0}^\infty \left(\frac{a_k}{x}\right)^i.
$$
From this is it clear that your $b_n$ coefficients are positive.

Comment: You're welcome. One further tip. When moving $\infty$ to $0$, I often find it's easier to move it in both the domain and the range. In other words, conjugate by $x\to x^{-1}$ and look at $1/f(1/x)=b_nx^n+b_{n+1}x^{n+1}+\cdots$. This does not, intrinsically, change much (unless you're planning to iterate $f$), but somehow power series in $x$ seem more appealing than power series in $1/x$.